# PHP Passing variable to iframe

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create PDF creator based on MPDF 6.0.

So I have page with input field that I want to pass to `iframe` where I've PDF preview. I want to make it editable in real time.

```
<iframe id="miniBrowser" style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;" src="generate_pdf.php"></iframe>
<style>
.worksheet {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:999999;
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0, 1, 0, 0.5);
    }
</style>

<div class="worksheet">
    <div id="usrform">
      EDIT: <input type="text" name="usrname">
      <button id='zapisz'>zapisz</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$("#zapisz").on( 'click', function () {
   var usrname = 'test';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'generate_pdf.php',
            data: ({usrnm:usrname}),
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
$('iframe').each(function() {
this.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
});

})
</script>
```

In `generate_pdf.php` I want to get `usrname` value and put in in html string which I convert later to PDF.

```
$f1 = $_POST['usrnm'];

$html = 'all the stuff for pdf here' . $f1 . 'more stuff';

include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c',array(297,210)); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why it doesn't work and how to pass variable to iframe.

Comment: Take a better look at ajax via jQuery. If you still have questions, ask a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right then i presume you want to get the value you have in your input to send to generate_pdf.php page:
well have you tried this

```
<div class="worksheet">
    <div id="usrform">
      EDIT: <input id='zapisz-username' type="text" name="usrname">
      <button id='zapisz'>zapisz</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>  
$("#zapisz").on( 'click', function () {
       var usrname = $('zapisz-username').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'generate_pdf.php',
                data: {'usrnm':usrname},
                success: function(data) {
                }
            });
```

Then that way in the generate_pdf.php page you can get the normal way you normally do it.

Comment: Whats the importance of this below line: $('iframe').each(function() {
this.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
});